# How to correctly string token in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I realize we can use `substring()` and `locate()` function for tokonization

I was tried query

```
insert into sum_of_counts
    select substring(pair,1,locate('|',pair)),
         sum(count)
    from em
    group by substring(pair,1,locate('|',pair))
```

for example : we use 'resumption|||resumption' as pair to query after `substring('resumption|||resumption',1,locate('|','resumption|||resumption'))`
it should be `resumption|` 
but after the query it appeared

```
+------------+------+
| wild_pair  | sum  |
+------------+------+
| resumption |    8 |
+------------+------+
```

the problem is we could find `'resumption|||resumption'` in `em` table
after I check the table `sum_of_counts` some of `wild_pair` are `word|` some of wild_pair are just `word`  how can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the structure of sum_of_counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  LEFT(`pair`, LOCATE('|||', `pair`)) `wild_pair`,
  SUM(count) `sum`
FROM `em`
GROUP BY `wild_pair`;
```

Should do the same thing easier.

If the **error occurs when inserting the result into another table**, check if the existing columns are wide enough to take the calculated data in full length.

Answer (score 0):

Your result should not be possible:

```
mysql> select locate('|', 'resumption|||resumption');
+----------------------------------------+
| locate('|', 'resumption|||resumption') |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                     11 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select substring('resumption|||resumption', 1, 11);
+---------------------------------------------+
| substring('resumption|||resumption', 1, 11) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| resumption|                                 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Are you sure that `pair` is always `foo|||bar` with 3 `|||`?

Comment: I'm sure all pair is  world|||word

Comment: then start some debugging: skip the insert, just select all the records and see WHICH of them is returning the `|` in there, then try to figure out WHY they're in there.

Comment: After testing  select substring(pair,1,locate('|',pair)),
         sum(count)
    from em
    group by substring(pair,1,locate('|',pair)) and all correct but after insert into table, some words get wrong